# Recover UTF-8 encoding in string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, utf-8, ascii

I'm working on my python script to extract multiple strings from a .csv file but I can't recover the Spanish characters (like á, é, í) after I open the file and read the lines.
This is my code so far:

```
import csv
list_text=[]

with open(file, 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]
        list_text.extend(row[0])
        print list_text
```

And I get something like this:

```
'Vivió el sueño, ESPAÑOL...'  ['Vivi\xc3\xb3 el sue\xc3\xb1o, ESPA\xc3\x91OL...']
```

I don't know why it prints it in the correct form but when I append it to the list is not correct.

**Edited:**
The problem is that I need to recover the characters because, after I read the file, the list has thousands of words in it and I don't need to print it I need to use regex to get rid of the punctuation, but this also deletes the backslash and the word is incomplete.

Comment: The short answer is to move to python 3 if you can. Its been out for nearly a decade.

Comment: Your edit highlights a very different problem. Its not getting rid of the backslashes - which aren't really there - that's just python's `repr` representation of a single non-printable byte. The regex module is also not very good at unicode. I wish you had mentioned that earlier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python 2.x `csv` module doesn't support unicode and you did the right thing by opening the file in binary mode and parsing the utf-8 encoded strings instead of decoded unicode strings. Python 2 is kinda strange in that the `str` type (as opposed to the `unicode` type) holds either string or binary data. You got `'Vivi\xc3\xb3 el sue\xc3\xb1o, ESPA\xc3\x91OL...'` which is the binary utf-8 encoding of the unicode.

We can decode it to get the unicode version...

```
>>> encoded_text = 'Vivi\xc3\xb3 el sue\xc3\xb1o, ESPA\xc3\x91OL...'
>>> text = encoded_text.decode('utf-8')
>>> print repr(text)
u'Vivi\xf3 el sue\xf1o, ESPA\xd1OL...'
>>> print text
Vivió el sueño, ESPAÑOL...
```

...but wait a second, the encoded text prints the same

```
>>> print encoded_text
Vivió el sueño, ESPAÑOL...
```

what's up with that? That has everything to do with your display surface which is a utf-8 encoded terminal. In the first case (`print text`), `text` is a unicode string so python has to encode it before sending it to the terminal which sees the utf-8 encoded version. In the second case its just a regular string and python sent it without conversion... but it just so happens it was holding encoded text which the terminal decoded.

Finally, when a string is in a list, python prints its `repr` representation, not its `str` value, as in

```
>>> print repr(encoded_text)
'Vivi\xc3\xb3 el sue\xc3\xb1o, ESPA\xc3\x91OL...'
```

To make things right, convert the cells in your rows to unicode after the csv module is done with them.

```
import csv
list_text=[]

with open(file, 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        row = [cell.decode('utf-8') for cell in row]
        print row[0]
        list_text.extend(row[0])
        print list_text
```

Comment: This isn't working properly I'm getting something like ` u'Vivi\xf3 el sue\xf1o, ESPA\xd1OL...' `. Each row is taken as a list and it has just one element, which is row[0] (a string). That's why I'm calling row[0]. What I want to do is recover the spanish characters

Comment: What isn't working? It decodes to a unicode string. Is the problem with a regex not shown here? If so, can you post that regex?

Comment: Once again, when you print a list you get a `repr` of its contents, not the `str`. So, a unicode string will print encased in `u'...'`. That's just python showing you a "programmers" view of the string.

Comment: I don't know your regex, but suppose you are trying to use character classes like `\w`. In python 2 those don't work for unicode either encoded or not. Another good reason to use python 3.

Comment: Nevermind, it worked, I wasn't understanding the unicode representation thing so I assumed it wasn't working, but you explainedit well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you print a list it shows all the cancelled characters, that way `\n` and other characters don't throw off the list display, so if you print the string it will work properly:

```
'Vivi\xc3\xb3 el sue\xc3\xb1o, ESPA\xc3\x91OL...'.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to recover the characters because, after I read the file, the list has thousands of words in it and I don't need to print it I need to use regex to get rid of the punctuation, but this also deletes the backslash and the word is incomplete.

Comment: Basically, those `\xc3` *isn't* literally `\xc3`, it's `Ã`. You can use regex normally with that.

Comment: `\xc3` is rendered as `Ã` in Latin-1 but this isn't Latin-1, it's a raw byte string. The byte alone in UTF-8 is simply the first byte of a multibyte character in the range U+00A0 to U+00CF (if I recall  the alignment boundaries correctly).

Comment: @tripleee Thanks! Wow.  Thanks.  Could you by chance explain what I should convert it to via `.encode` or is it not that sort of thing?

Comment: If it's valid UTF-8, you `.decode('utf-8')` to convert it to a Unicode string.

Answer (score 0):

1. use unicodecsv instead of csv , csv doesn't support well unicode
2. open the file with codecs, and 'utf-8'

**see  code below**

```
import unicodecsv as csv
import codecs 
list_text=[]

with codecs.open(file, 'rb','utf-8') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]
        list_text.extend(row[0])
        print list_text
```